# Ajax JSON.parse JSONarray

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am trying populate a form from a mysqli database when an option is selected from a drop down. I am trying to do this with an ajax 'get' call to a PHP page. The PHP page does the SQL query and returns the results, then I do a json_encode of the data. This puts the JSON into an array. Then the ajax function attempts to parse the JSON. However this is where the problem lies. The JSON data comes in as an array and the JSON.parse(xhr.response) fails to parse.

```
[{"id":"12","accountnum":"2148","name":"Blah","address":"123 Dan Hwy","city":"ANY Town","state":"IA","zip":"11111","phonenumber":"555-555-5555","brand":"Dan","create_date":"2021-06-14 15:47:36"}]
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<script>
  const selectElement = document.querySelector('.accountnum');
  selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) =>{
    const result = document.querySelector('.result');
    var eventResponse = `${event.target.value}`;
    result.textContent = 'the account num is ' +eventResponse;
    loadAccounts(eventResponse);
  });
</script>
```

///////////////////////////////////////

```
  function loadAccounts(eventResponse){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "users.php";
    var geturl = xhr.open('GET', url+"?accountnum="+eventResponse, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if(this.status == 200){
          console.log(xhr.response);
          var accounts = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
          console.log(accounts.id);
          console.log(accounts.name);
          var output = '';

        for(var i in accounts){
          output += '<div class="form-group">' +
            '<label for="accountname">AccountNum*</label>' +
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="accountnum" name="accountnum" value= '+accounts[i].accountnum+ '>' +
            '</div>'
          
        }
        document.getElementById('accounts').innerHTML = output;
      }
    }
    }
    xhr.send()
  }
</script>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<?php
      
      $accountnum = $_GET['accountnum'];
      $query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE accountnum = $accountnum";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      $accounts = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      echo json_encode($accounts);

   ?>
```

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah this is just a quick and dirty example. I will be cleaning it up before we go live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is an array, not an object. Try reassigning the accounts variable like `accounts = accounts[0];`. Or make your php script extract the first element from the result set and json encode it loke `echo $accounts[0] ?? null;`

Comment: OK that is working. But now I am only getting the first part of the return value. For instance if the returned "name" value if "Dan's Garage" I am only seeing "Dan's". However if I look at the JSON array, all values are intact.

Comment: That is a separate issue, may be your data is not escaped properly. Try escaping the data or debug it separately. Have you tried logging the data before and after the JSON.parse?

Comment: If I console.log(accounts[i].name) then I see the full account name, so it's being parsed corrctly now. But if I "input type=text value=accounts[i].name" then I only see the first part.